# IAM Role to SSH to VM without Admin Priveleges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

**Background**

To ssh into VM instances in Google Compute Engine,i need to provide instanceAdmin Role to the user,which gives Admin Control to the User,that sometimes could be a security issue.

**Query**

Does Google Compute Engine provide any IAM Role,which will allow the User to SSH to instances,run programs on it but not have Admin Access(Not Provide instanceAdmin Role to User)??

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** - No, with [the list of Google Compute engine (GCE) IAM roles provided](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam), you cannot use IAM roles to achieve what you are asking.

## IAM roles for SSH key provisioning

The following roles allow SSH into GCE VMs:

`Compute Engine Instance Admin` aka `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`
`Service account actor` aka `roles/iam.serviceAccountActor`

## Provisioning SSH keys

Since GCE uses metadata server to provision the SSH keys, you will need the permission `compute.instances.setMetadata` to provision the keys. After the provisioning is done, you will have to use a custom mechanism of your own to distribute the keys.

In other words, you will have to take care of creating additional users yourself on the GCE instance with the desired permissions and controlling provisioning/distribution of the SSH keys to the desired user.

GCE provides tools to manage SSH keys using either the REST APIs or `gcloud`.

Do read the following guides which explain the process in detail:

- [SSH Keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh-keys)
- [Adding and removing SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)
- [Provisioning the keys on the client side and connecting to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)

## [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh-keys#supported_images)

GCE will use the metadata server to provision the SSH keys and it is supported only on the following images which were created after Feb/Mar 2016.

> - CentOS 6 and 7  February 10th, 2016
> - Debian 8    February 10th, 2016
> - openSUSE 13 February 10th, 2016
> - RHEL 6 and 7    February 10th, 2016
> - SUSE 11 and 12  March 1st, 2016
> - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS  March 3rd, 2016
> - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS    March 29th, 2016

Comment: This answer may be outdated now. See my reply

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the `Compute OS Login` and `Service Account User` IAM role along with setting the `enable-oslogin` metadata on the instance to `true`.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access

Comment: Create a custom role with sub permission of all mentioned roles, and it works like charm.